# Flask Redirect Returns 200 Instead of 302

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I'm writing unit tests for a Flask application and am not sure why the reponses are returning status code 200 instead of 302.  The view I'm testing is using redirect and my post has `follow_redirects=False` set.

Below is the test and view code:

```
#test_views.py
def test_can_post_new_engagement(self):
        response = self.client.post(
                    url_for('main.new_engagement'),
                    data={
                        'title': 'Sample Title',
                        'client': 1},
                    follow_redirects=False)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

#views.py
@main.route('/engagement/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_engagement():
    form = EngagementForm()
    form.client.choices = [(o.id, o.official_name) for o in
                           Organization.query.order_by('official_name')]
    form.client.choices.insert(0, (0, '--- Select Organization ---'))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        eng = Engagement(title=form.title.data,
                         client_id=form.client.data)
        db.session.add(eng)
        return redirect(url_for('main.new_pentest'))
    return render_template('engagement_form.html', form=form)
```

**Error:**

```
 FAIL: test_can_post_new_engagement (test_views.NewEngagementView)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ramces/dev/global_engagement_manager/tests/unit/test_views.py
    ", line 36, in test_can_post_new_engagement
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flask redirect function **does** return a response with code `302`

```
from flask import redirect
print(redirect("some_url").status_code)  # 302
```

Your test is probably failing because your form validation fails.
Can you make sure that you are indeed entering the if-branch?

One problem could be that your `client` `SelectField` (assuming you are using `wtforms`) uses `int` as keys. Make sure that you provide `coerce=int` in the field's constructor.

I am using flask version *0.10.1*

*note: this should probably be a comment, but SO tells me i need 50 rep before commenting. But posting an answer is fine, of course.*

Comment: It seems I spent too much time in front of my screen yesterday.  :)  The form wasn't validating properly.  Coercion was set to int... problem was something else.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**Resolution**

First, as Wombatz suggested, I didn't realize my form was not passing `form.validate_on_submit()`.

After a little bit of debugging, I realized the CSRF token was missing from my testing configuration, so adding `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False` resolved this.